# Import Data from SQL Azure to Excel Using AAD authentication and sharing a link of excel online

Tags: excel, azure-sql-database, office365, azure-active-directory, powerquery

**The Scenario** 
 
Step 1:- User clicks a link which redirects to excel online. 
Step 2:- The excel on load will fetch the data from SQL azure (or can use ODATA feed ) using logged in user ID. (some custom logic to filter data based on user).

I did some research and can see excel power query as an option, but i cannot provide SQL server authentication for fetching data from SQL azure,  because i need the logged in User details. I tried using Azure AAD authentication for SQL azure, but seems like power query does not have that option either to connect to SQL azure with AAD integrated Authentication. For OData i can use custom authorization implementation but how do i get the user information (logged into excel online) and pass it to Odata.

Looking for help in two major parts:-

1) Any pointers on step 1, do i have to put a excel sheet somewhere in share point (any other options??) and share the link? in that case how does it work if two different set of users (who see data filtered based on permissions) will work?  
2) Help on step 2, how do i bring the data to excel with SQL azure or using ODATA but based on logged in user.

P.S :- Correct me if i am in completely wrong direction or any better ideas to implement this scenario.

Comment: Currently AADA for SQL Azure isn't supported with Excel currently. What you are looking for would probably involve some custom work.

Comment: what custom work you are speaking? can you be more specific? i would be happy to do any custom work.

Comment: Excel is not suitable for loading data based on logged user. For example, several users may edit the same spreadsheet together. Have you considered using the Access Web App?